# Google script compare two columns from differents spreadsheets with if

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a table in one spreadsheet and another table with an equal column in another spreadsheet, i try with an `if` to compare two columns of each spreadsheet and if the values ​​matched, they will copy the values ​​from the next column to the other spreadsheet like this...

`city number`    ---------`city    number`
 `Mad    1`     ---------------------------`1`
  `Bar    2`   ---------------------------`1`     if the name matches or is the same the other spreadsheet
  `Sev    3`      ---------------------------`1`

then it copies like this...

`city   number`
`Mad` -------`1`
`Mad` -------`1`
`Mad` -------`1`

I have the following code but I know that it probably is not the correct way to do it or this incomplete...

```
//this its the spreadsheet one
function hoja1(){
var ss =
SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID")
.getSheetByName("city");
var city = ss.getRange("A2:A");
var number = ss.getRange("B2:B").getValues(); 
var lr = city.getLastRow();

//this is the spreadsheet two
var ss2 = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID")
.getSheetByName("CITY");
var number2 = ss2.getRange("B2:B").getValues();

if( number2 == number ){
  var set = ss2.getRange(2,1, lr, 1).setValues(city);
}

}
```

Could someone help me complete it or correct me wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need a for loop.

Comment: GetValues() return type is an array, you're comparing variables not arrays. Either specify the index of the array or use GetValue() instead